# Linear Algebra - Subspaces (proving)

Tags: linear-algebra

Having a bit of trouble with these 3 questions on subspaces. I understand that a set $V$ is a subspace of $R^n$ when:

1. the $0$ vector is in $V$
2. if $u,v$ are in $V$ then $u+v$ is in $V$
3. if $u$ is in $V$ and $C$ is in $R$ then $cu$ is in $V$

I'm quite unsure how to approach these questions;

Which are the following are subspaces, show that they are or explain why they are not:

A) the set of elements $(x_1,.....,x_n)$ with $x_1-x_2=9$ inside $R^n$

B) the set of elements $(x_1,.....,x_n)$ with $x_1+x_2-x_3\ge0$ inside $R^n$

C) the set of polynomials, with real coefficients,s such that $p(0) + p(3) = p(4)$ inside $P_n$

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Apply what you stated earlier , which part are you stuck at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if 1,2,3 hold.

A) It's not a subspace, since $x_1 - x_2 = 9$ then $x_1$ and $x_2$ can't be at the same time $0$, so 1. doesn't hold.

B)1. holds obviously.

If you take u=$(x_1,.....,x_n)$ and v=$(y_1,.....,y_n)$ then $x_1+x_2-x_3\ge0$ and $y_1+y_2-y_3\ge0$ . Adding those two together $(x_1+y_1)+(x_2+y_2)-(x_3+y_3)\ge0$  so the inequality holds for $u+v$, therefore 2.holds. Lets see about 3.Say we have $\vec{x}=(x_1,.....,x_n)$ with $x_1+x_2-x_3\ge0$. Then if $c \le 0$ the inequality for $c \vec{x}$ will be reversed. So it's not a subsace since 3. doesn't hold.

With these in mind, see if you can do C) on your own, if not ask me in the comments.

Comment: "then x1 and x2 can't be at the same time  0" - what do you mean by this?, will try to attempt c now, many thanks :)

Comment: @Reety You need "zero" to be an element of the vector space for whatever concept of zero makes sense.  In the case of $\Bbb R^n$ with the usual addition and scalar multiplication, the zero vector would be $(0,0,0,\dots,0)$, the $n$-tuple with all entries equal to zero.  Notice that $(0,0,0,\dots,0)$ however is not an element of your set in part (A) since it does not satisfy the defining property to be in the set, namely for the difference of the first two entries to be nine.

Comment: @Dimitris right i kind of understand it now, so say the set of elements of (x1,....,xn) with 6x1+4x2=x3 inside R^n, would that be a subspace, since it can contain the 0 vector, but how would i prove 2 and 3?

Comment: @Dimitris and for C) this is not a subspace because it is not closed under scalar multiplication? and how would i show this mathematically?

Comment: @JMoravitz if you could also help me on this would be great, thanks

Comment: @reety *if* C) was in fact not closed under scalar multiplication then you would need to give an example of an element in the set and a scalar whose product was *not* in the set.  You'll have a hard time finding such a pair though since it is in fact closed under scalar multiplication (assuming scalar field is the reals).  To show this, take an arbitrary element of the set, which by nature of being in the set must satisfy the stated properties, and then multiply it by an arbitrary scalar. Check if the result also satisfies the necessary properties to be in the set.